# Switch Inside IF statement gives Switch is not recognized

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to Power BI and need your assistance. I'm trying to create a new column based on two columns, `OS_NAME` and `OS_BUILD`. If `OS_Name = VMWare` then check the build number. Based on the build number it should populate the column as compliant of not.

Please help me.

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded ORG1 MACHINE_VIRTUAL_HOST", "Compliance", each 

if([OS_NAME] = "VMware vCenter Server 7.0.2") 
 then
        switch ( 
            
                [OS_BUILD] < 17630552, "Non-Compliant",
                 [OS_BUILD] >= 17630552, "Compliant"
        )
else if ([OS_NAME] = "VMware vCenter Server 6.7.0")
    then
        switch ( 
                 [OS_BUILD] < 17630552, "Non-Compliant",
                 [OS_BUILD] >= 17630552, "Compliant",
        )
else if ([OS_NAME] = "VMware vCenter Server 6.5.0")
    then
        switch( 
            
                [OS_BUILD] < 17630552, "Non-Compliant",
                 [OS_BUILD] >= 17630552, "Compliant"
        )

else "Older Version")
```

Comment: If the answer provided by Marcus has helped solve your problem, I invite you to [mark it as accepted and/or upvote it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: There is no `SWITCH` function in Power Query. You will have to manually nest your `IF` statements in your code.

Edit: You can add this code as a custom column to produce what you are after:

```
if List.Contains( 
            { 
                "VMware vCenter Server 7.0.2" ,
                "VMware vCenter Server 6.7.0" ,
                "VMware vCenter Server 6.5.0"
            },
        [OS_NAME] ) 
        then 
            if [OS_BUILD] >= 17630552 
            then "Compliant"
            else "Non-compliant"
        else "Older Version"
```

If you need to have different builds for different OS versions, I would recommend to have a different table that stores a row for each OS version with the corresponding "compliant build limit":

| OS_NAME | COMPLIANT_BUILD |
| --- | --- |
| VMware vCenter Server 7.0.2 | 2000 |
| VMware vCenter Server 6.7.0 | 1700 |
| VMware vCenter Server 6.5.0 | 1500 |

You can then join this into your main table, expand the `COMPLIANT_BUILD` column and do a simple conditional column:

```
each if [COMPLIANT_BUILD] = null then "Older Version"
else if [OS_BUILD] >= [COMPLIANT_BUILD] then "Compliant"
else "Not compliant"
```

Comment: that looks pretty much simple. another question just strike my mind.
Basically with vmware vulnerability and action announcements, each version will have its own build number. how can I write it in that case?

Below is my actual SQL query:

Comment: probably split the List.Contains into multiple?

Comment: Please see my response. It would make more sense to do a join and maintain a simple spreadsheet that contains `OS_VERSION` with `COMPLIANT_BUILD` and join in this table before doing a simple comparison to output your `Compliance` column,